# Exclude certain directories from ls and copy the remaining over to a shared path

Tags: linux, scp, ls

I have a folder that contains sub-directories `A,B,C and D`. I need to copy directories `A and D` to another directory called `'copy'` while excluding `B and C`(i.e. B and C doesn't get copied over). I was thinking about doing the following (in command-line pseudocode):

```
ls (selective ls on the source directory) | 
   scp -r {returned value from the ls} {target directory}
```

Is there a Linux command-line way to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to only copy the directories you want:

```
scp -r A D anotherhost:/path/to/target/directory
```

This will do exactly what you've described in your example.  A more general solution might look something like this:

```
scp -r $(ls | egrep -v '^(B|C)$') anotherhost:/path/to/target/directory
```

This command will work as long as the number of files in your source directory is not large.  As the number of files goes up, you'll eventually run into a "command too long" error.

Instead of using `scp`, you could use `rsync`, which has a variety of mechanisms for including/excluding files.  For example:

```
rsync --exclude='B/' --exclude='C/' . anotherhost:/path/to/target/directory
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using find for this.

Let's create some test subjects:

```
$ mkdir -p ./testing/test{1,2,3,4}
$ touch ./testing/test{1,2,3,4}/test{a,b}
```

Will result in:

```
$ ls -R ./testing
./testing:
test1  test2  test3  test4

./testing/test1:
testa  testb

./testing/test2:
testa  testb

./testing/test3:
testa  testb

./testing/test4:
testa  testb
```

Now, run

```
$ mkdir ./testing/copy
$ find ./testing/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name test1 ! -name test3 ! -name copy -execdir cp -R '{}' ./copy/ ';'
```

Will result in:

```
$ ls -R ./testing/
./testing/:
copy  test1  test2  test3  test4

./testing/copy:
test2  test4

./testing/copy/test2:
testa  testb

./testing/copy/test4:
testa  testb

./testing/test1:
testa  testb

./testing/test2:
testa  testb

./testing/test3:
testa  testb

./testing/test4:
testa  testb
```

Background information:

*Summary: find the directories which need to be copied and execute the copy command. In this case, let's copy all directories but 'test1' and 'test3'.*

The **-mindepth 1** option will prevent find from including the . and possibly .. directories, since these are on depth 0.

The **-maxdepth 1** option will prevent find from copying every single subdirectory individually. The command cp -R handles the subdirectories, so they are covered.

Use **-execdir** instead of -exec, so you don't have to include the whole path as the target directory for cp command.

**DO NOT forget to mkdir your target directory before running find, and DO NOT forget to exclude this directory from the result! Hence the *! -name copy* option in my example.**

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you really know your directories, simply add all to the scp:

```
scp A/* D/* targetHost:/copy
```

The only problem with this solution is, that it "mixes" your files in the copy directory. Probably, it dosen't matter :-)